# How to get image from server using NSUrlConnection

Tags: iphone, ios, objective-c, nsurlconnection

How to get image from server by sending one parameter with url.

GET HTTPRequest has to be use to send request.

Comment: Google has lots of Answers for this Question.

Comment: can you tell me some code or suggestions

Comment: @IOS_5555: I already gave you Suggestion. Did you see ?

Comment: Thanks to all, I solved this myself

Comment: please correct your spelling

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can get image from server with specific path of that image with image name.

```
UIImage* serverImage = [UIImage imageWithData:[NSData dataWithContentsOfURL:[NSURL URLWithString: @"http://example.com/image_name.png"]]];
```

then you can use `serverImage` anywhere you want.

Answer (score 2):

Try to use this :

```
-(UIImage*)getImageFromURLwithUrl:(NSString*)imgURLStr
{
    NSMutableURLRequest *requestWithBodyParams = [NSMutableURLRequest requestWithURL:[NSURL URLWithString:imgURLStr]];
    NSData *imageData = [NSURLConnection sendSynchronousRequest:requestWithBodyParams returningResponse:nil error:nil];
    UIImage *image = [UIImage imageWithData:imageData];

    return image;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

A pretty useful project that I use to load Images without blocking the UI is the [SDWebImage](https://github.com/rs/SDWebImage).
It adds an asynchronous category on UIImageView, enabling you to load an image with just one line of code:

```
[myImageView setImageWithURL:[NSURL URLWithString:@"http://www.domain.com/path/to/image.jpg"]
               placeholderImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"placeholder.png"]];
```

Comment: It's u blocking the UI. You are updating your UI after download finished, you should use this asynchronously. And it's `SDWebImage`'s duty to update your UI on main thread.

Comment: Exactly, so the above code is not blocking the main thread since SDWebImage is downloading on a background thread and then updating on the main thread after it's done.