# How could i load URL from NSArray

Tags: ios, url, nsarray

I use random() to make a NSMutableArray  and in the NSMutableArray have NSUrl for loading image to paste on every tableview header

```
NSMutableArray *imagearray = [[NSMutableArray alloc]init];

for (int i = 0;i < 10; i++)
{
    [imagearray addObject:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"http://flicksbank.console360.net/images/%@/default.jpg",randomArray[i][@"id"]]];
}

[imagearray setImageWithURL:[NSURL URLWithString:url1] placeholderImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"video-bg.png"]];
```

Comment: You want to download the image from the URL? if it is, check this thread http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17365135/how-to-get-image-from-server-using-nsurlconnection

Comment: Your question is not clear, also what do you mean by                              [imagearray setImageWithURL:[NSURL URLWithString:url1] placeholderImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"video-bg.png"]];

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think r u used in the `AFNetworking` Image cache method, In here your mistake is

you called the `setImageWithURL` for `NSMutableArray` it is 100 % wrong .

```
[imagearray setImageWithURL:[NSURL URLWithString:url1] placeholderImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"video-bg.png"]];
```

you need to do like

```
 -(UIView *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView viewForHeaderInSection:(NSInteger)section
{
    UIView *teamview = [[UIView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, tableView.frame.size.width, 18)];
    /* Create custom view to display section header... */
      UIImageView *imageView = [[UIImageView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, tableView.frame.size.width, 18)];
      [imageView setImageWithURL:[NSURL URLWithString:url1] placeholderImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"video-bg.png"]];
    [teamview addSubview:imageView];
    [teamview setBackgroundColor:[UIColor colorWithRed:166/255.0 green:177/255.0 blue:186/255.0 alpha:1.0]]; //your background color...
    return teamview;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

**If there were many URL's you can store in array and store objects in NSString by objectatindex**

**But if there is single URL so You dont need to store URL to an array. You can directly get image form url by using below function**

**To get image from url Declare the below Function**

> ```
> -(UIImage *) getImageFromURL:(NSString *)fileURL  {
>     NSURL *url = [NSURL URLWithString:
>                   fileURL];
>     UIImage *image = [UIImage imageWithData: [NSData dataWithContentsOfURL:url]];
>
>     return image;
>      }
> ```

**You have to store url into string like**

> NSString *imageurl =
>   @"Your URLPath HERE for Image";

You have your imageview and call the below method to assign that image from url

> self."Yourimageview".image=[self getImageFromURL:imageurl];

Hope this will work for you